# Wildfly 10 ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender

Tags: log4j, wildfly-10

I'm using Wildfly 10 in standalone mode,  when I start Wildfly, I saw the the error message saying

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender from [Module "org.jboss.log4j.logmanager:main" from local module loader @33e5ccce (finder: local module finder @5a42bbf4 (roots: /opt/jboss/modules,/opt/jboss/modules/system/layers/base))]
```

I Unzipped the jar files under modules directory, it seems that the `DailyRollingFileAppender` class is under `org.apache.log4j`, not `org.jboss.logging`.  I'm not sure if I need to do any configurations.

And another thing is: this error message only shows up on console, not in my log file, not sure why. Other error messages showed up in my log file.

The following is the stack trace:

```
10:26:21,167 ERROR [stderr] log4j:ERROR Could not create an Appender. Reported error follows.
10:26:21,174 ERROR [stderr] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender from [Module "org.jboss.log4j.logmanager:main" from local module loader @33e5ccce (finder: local module finder @5a42bbf4 (roots: /opt/jboss/modules,/opt/jboss/modules/system/layers/base))]
10:26:21,174 ERROR [stderr]     at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
10:26:21,174 ERROR [stderr]     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
10:26:21,174 ERROR [stderr]     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
10:26:21,174 ERROR [stderr]     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
10:26:21,174 ERROR [stderr]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
10:26:21,175 ERROR [stderr]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
10:26:21,175 ERROR [stderr]     at org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:198)
10:26:21,175 ERROR [stderr]     at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.java:247)
10:26:21,175 ERROR [stderr]     at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurator.java:176)
10:26:21,175 ERROR [stderr]     at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfigurator.java:191)
10:26:21,175 ERROR [stderr]     at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOMConfigurator.java:523)
10:26:21,175 ERROR [stderr]     at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseRoot(DOMConfigurator.java:492)
10:26:21,175 ERROR [stderr]     at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:1001)
10:26:21,175 ERROR [stderr]     at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:867)
10:26:21,176 ERROR [stderr]     at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:794)
10:26:21,176 ERROR [stderr]     at org.jboss.as.logging.deployments.LoggingConfigDeploymentProcessor.configure(LoggingConfigDeploymentProcessor.java:238)
10:26:21,176 ERROR [stderr]     at org.jboss.as.logging.deployments.LoggingConfigDeploymentProcessor.processDeployment(LoggingConfigDeploymentProcessor.java:114)
10:26:21,176 ERROR [stderr]     at org.jboss.as.logging.deployments.LoggingConfigDeploymentProcessor.processDeployment(LoggingConfigDeploymentProcessor.java:144)
10:26:21,176 ERROR [stderr]     at org.jboss.as.logging.deployments.AbstractLoggingDeploymentProcessor.deploy(AbstractLoggingDeploymentProcessor.java:67)
10:26:21,176 ERROR [stderr]     at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
10:26:21,176 ERROR [stderr]     at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
10:26:21,176 ERROR [stderr]     at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
10:26:21,176 ERROR [stderr]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
10:26:21,177 ERROR [stderr]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
10:26:21,177 ERROR [stderr]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks, Helen

Answer (score 1):

I got help from Jboss community, I had an app which has log4j.xml packaged inside the war file and used org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender. This log4j.xml caused this error message.  Setting use-deployment-logging-config to be false in standalone.xml logging subsystem solved this problem.

Helen